# 'MainPageDataController' doesn't comfirm to the bound 'StateNotifier<MainPageData>' of the type parameter 'Notifier'

Tags: flutter, dart, state, riverpod

can anyone try to explain to me why this is happening as per the example of riverpod (stateNotifierProvider) it is actually right but I get this error which I am unable to rectify thanks in advance
my code goes like this

```
final mainPageDataControllerProvider =
StateNotifierProvider<MainPageDataController, MainPageData>((ref) {
return MainPageDataController();
});

    class MainPageDataController extends StateNotifier<MainPageData> {
MainPageDataController([MainPageData? state])
    : super(state ?? MainPageData.inital()) {
getMovies();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have similar issue where StateNotifier on Provider wrongly detect its class type, it says `StateNotifier<dynamic>`. I fix it by **reimporting the class type**. I think its just lint problem, likely because of file name change or location change.

In your case try removing `MainPageData` import. then import it again.